# Entity Framework : value from textfield in view return null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to filter some list with input from the user. I created the view, and used the columns that it auto-generated. No problem with the column Codigo, but with Cedula, or Email, it doesn't work, and I need to use textboxes which do work.

```
Buscar expediente Solicitante por celuda: @Html.TextBox("Cedula")<br/>
Buscar expediente funcionario por celuda: @Html.TextBox("Email")<br />
```

Here is the code of my controller. When I put something in the textfield Codigo it gets the value without problem, but when I do the same on Cedula or Email it only gets null. Any idea whats going on?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BuscarExpediente(int? Codigo , int? Cedula, string Email)
{
    //Expediente expediente = db.Expediente.Find(id);
    //var expediente = db.Expediente.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Codigo == id);
    //si me dan el id de expediente lo busco de esta forma
    if ((Codigo != null) &&(Cedula == null) &&(Email == null))
    {
        //var expediente = db.Expediente.Where(E => E.Codigo == Codigo).SingleOrDefault();
        //return View(expediente);
        TempData["idExpedienteBuscar"] = Codigo;
        return RedirectToAction("ExpedientesPorId");
    }

    //si me dal la cedula de un solicitante busco de esta forma
    if((Cedula != null)&& (Email == null)&& (Codigo == null))
    {
        TempData["ExpedientesCedulaSolicitante"] = Cedula;
        return RedirectToAction("ExpedientesPorCedulaSolicitante");
    }

    //si me dan un funcionario busco de esta forma
    if((Email != null)&& (Codigo == null) && (Cedula == null))
    {
        TempData["ExpedienteBuscarFuncionarioID"] = Email;
        return RedirectToAction("ExpedientesPorFuncionario");
    }
    //si no me dan nada busco de estra otra
    else
    {
        //que de el mensaje de que solo se puede insertar un campo de busqueda
        //hay que poner en el view un label o algo para tirar el msj
    }

    //ViewBag.FechInicio = expediente.FechaCreacion;
    //ViewBag.Tramite = expediente.Tramite.Titulo;
    //ViewBag.Funcionario = expediente.Funcionario.Nombre;
    return View();
}
```

Here is the code of the view

```
@model Entrega02Programacion03.Models.Expediente

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BuscarExpediente";
}

<h2>BuscarExpediente</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Expediente</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Codigo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Codigo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Codigo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
       @* Buscar expediente Solicitante por celuda: @Html.TextBox("Cedula")<br/>
        Buscar expediente funcionario por celuda: @Html.TextBox("Email")<br />*@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Solicitante.Cedula , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Solicitante.Cedula, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Solicitante.Cedula, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Funcionario.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Funcionario.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Funcionario.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.abierto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.abierto, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.abierto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Buscar Expediente" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}

        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you access the field "abierto" without problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the fields that aren't accessible because they aren't on the "root" level - they are available "inside" other models. Try switching your model to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BuscarExpediente(Entrega02Programacion03.Models.Expediente model)
{
    int? Codigo = model.Codigo;
    int? Cedula = model.Solicitante?.Cedula;
    string Email = model.Funcionario?.Email;

    //Expediente expediente = db.Expediente.Find(id);
    //var expediente = db.Expediente.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Codigo == id);
    //si me dan el id de expediente lo busco de esta forma
    if ((Codigo != null) &&(Cedula == null) &&(Email == null))
    {

        //var expediente = db.Expediente.Where(E => E.Codigo == Codigo).SingleOrDefault();
        //return View(expediente);
        TempData["idExpedienteBuscar"] = Codigo;
        return RedirectToAction("ExpedientesPorId");

    }
    //si me dal la cedula de un solicitante busco de esta forma
    if((Cedula != null)&& (Email == null)&& (Codigo == null))
    {
        TempData["ExpedientesCedulaSolicitante"] = Cedula;
        return RedirectToAction("ExpedientesPorCedulaSolicitante");

    }
    //si me dan un funcionario busco de esta forma
    if((Email != null)&& (Codigo == null) && (Cedula == null))
    {
        TempData["ExpedienteBuscarFuncionarioID"] = Email;
        return RedirectToAction("ExpedientesPorFuncionario");
    }
    //si no me dan nada busco de estra otra
     else
    {
        //que de el mensaje de que solo se puede insertar un campo de busqueda
        //hay que poner en el view un label o algo para tirar el msj
    }

    //ViewBag.FechInicio = expediente.FechaCreacion;
    //ViewBag.Tramite = expediente.Tramite.Titulo;
    //ViewBag.Funcionario = expediente.Funcionario.Nombre;
    return View();
}
```